# How to display the value?

Tags: php, php-curl

How to echo out the value of `username`, `coins` and `cash`.

```
Array(
    [code] => 1
    [msg] => Success
    [data] => 
        Array(
            [userid] =>29657587
            [code] =>0205994641
            [email] =>
            [areacode] =>
            [phone] =>                                     
            [username] => John
            [lastname] => Go
            [nickname] => John Go
            [headpic] => avatar/20200403/09910e482b5d3bg1.jpeg
            [birthday] => 771811200000
            [gender] => 1
            [coins] => 663
            [cash] => 1.41
            [centBalance] => 141
            [coinBalance] => 663
            [regtime] => 1585935551000                     
            [paypal_email] => 1234567@gmail.com
            [delivery_address] => 
                Array(
                    [zipcode] =>                           
                    [phone] =>
                    [addr1] =>
                    [city] =>
                    [name] =>
                    [state] =>
                    [addr] =>
                    [lastname] =>
                )
            [scratch_card_num] => 0
            [box_unused_num] => 0
            [debris_new_num] => 0           
            [debris_synthesizable_num] => 0
            [notificationNum] => 0
            [badge] => 0
            [badgeExcludeClapTeam] => 0
            [showCashOutGuide] =>           
            [finishPreRewardGuide] => 1
            [chest] => 0            
            [reviewModeUnlocked] =>
            [countryCode2] => US
            [address] =>
            [paypal] => 
                Array(
                    [country] => US                    
                    [street_address] => US
                    [locality] => US
                    [email] => 123456@gmail.com
                )
            [paypal_account] => 123456@gmail.com
        )
        [date] => 1589568315345
   )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This can come across as asking others to just do the code for you.

Comment: I tried foreach loop but not working